# .Net Core Model Binding JSON Post To Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding, asp.net-core-webapi

Just started a new project using .NET Core. Added my Web API controller and related method. Using Postman I created a JSON object and posted it to my controller method. Bear in mind the JSON object matches the Object param in the controller method exactly.

In debug mode I can see the object, it is not null, the properties are there, HOWEVER the prop values are defaulted to their representatives types, `0` for `int`, etc.

I've never seen this behavior before… so I took exactly the same code and object and replicated in a MVC project with a Web API 2 controller and it works perfectly.

What am I missing, can I not POST JSON and model bind in .NET Core?

Reading this article it seems I cannot unless I send as form POST or as querystring vars which by the way works fine.

https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/web-api-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-6-asp-net-5/

JSON:

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "userId": "3"
   "dateOfTest": "7/13/2017"
}
```

Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test1")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Test(Class1 data)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add, if you are using core 3.1 and above, you default to using the System.Text.Json for your conversions. As of now, it only serializes/deserializes properties only and so your class need to use properties instead of fields as in the answer by edincorbin.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**NOTE: If you are using aspnet core 3.0, the solution can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  For other versions, keep reading.**

You need to mark your parameter as coming from the body with the `FromBody` attribute like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test1")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody] Class1 data)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

You need to make sure you're using `application/json` as your content type from Postman:

[image: Postman application/json]

Resulting in:

[image: json POST action]

Make sure your property setters are public as well:

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name;
    public Int32 Age;
}
```

Comment: So that is how I had it originally and the object Class1 was null

Comment: So does it work now? Will edit the answer just to clarify headers.

Comment: @MikeAnderson: Assuming you have `[FromBody]`, the only other reason `data` would be null is if none of the posted names matched up with properties on `Class1`. The modelbinder will only instantiate the class if there's something to instantiate it with (i.e. at least one property on the class has a value).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I see the issue now. The object I was attempting to bind to is an EF generated object. When I created just the class without the EF added constructor and virtual prop, it works like magic lol. So I guess in order for this work in CORE I cannot use persistent models generated by EF, I have to create my own DTO or VM.

Which is best practice anyways...thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU for your bold note on net core 3.0.  I've literally been searching for a whole day trying to figure out the issue and nothing else had worked until that.

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with this too, and thought I would share one item that was necessary for me and not in the accepted answer, I needed to add {get; set;} to each attribute in my class as so:

```
    public class LogString{
        public string val {get; set;}
        public string data {get; set;}
    }
```

The rest was the same:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] LogString message)
        {      
            Console.WriteLine(message.val);
        }
```

After adding that it started working.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I haven't seen anywhere in the documentation that says you need to use properties instead of member variables! This is frustrating.

Comment: Agrrr {get; set;}  in one class was missing for all properties, wasted an hour! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have an **ASP.Net Core 3.1** application and for me, none of these solutions worked. I lost a few hairs (and hours of work) until I found the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1

In short :

1. Install the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson** NuGet package.
2. Update the project's Startup.ConfigureServices method to call **AddNewtonsoftJson**. For example:

   ```cs
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddRazorPages()
           .AddNewtonsoftJson();//this is important
   }
   ```

That's it ! I don't need the **`[FromBody]`** attribute.

If it doesn't work, verify that your model's properties have setters (for example `public string Message { get; set; }`). **Don't forget the setter.**

Answer (score 2):

**Consider *Properties* instead of *Fields* on your binding objects**

On .NET 5, I had to add `{get; set;}` to my public fields to turn them into properties to get them to populate.

Either the model binder in .NET 5 can't work with fields or you have to do something special to make it populate them. I don't know which. It took a few minutes to turn all my fields into properties, so I wasn't going to spend time trying to figure out how to configure it to work with fields.

Note: If you have this problem with request objects, you will probably also have the same issue with response objects.

Comment: Converted to .NET 5 and spent 2 hours understanding why things do not work any more. 
{get; set;} was a culprit in one class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this issue for several hours and none of existing solutions worked for me, but turned out that I had no public parameterless constructor for class of incoming instance. In this case, `Class1` had only protected constructors and parameter was always null no matter what. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is coming to this question and like me you are used to working with .Net Framework MVC you may be creating the JSON object similar to this -

```
 this.http.post<Stock>("/api/Stock2", { Stock: this.SelectedStock }, this.httpOptions)
```

and then expecting it to bound to 'Stock'

```
[HttpPost("Stock2")]
    public JsonResult Stock2(ConsolidatedStock Stock) {
        return this.Json(1);
    }
```

This will no longer work in .net core, you need to change how you build the JSON -

```
 this.http.post<Stock>("/api/Stock2", this.SelectedStock, this.httpOptions)
```

If you want to post multiple objects, you would need to create a new model to hold those objects, for example

```
public class StockViewModel {
    public ConsolidatedStock Stock { get; set; }
}
```