# How to post to MVC endpoint via postman with JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I have a JSON object and trying to have a post request to my API endpoint.

In my Listing controller I have the following function

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Import(GetImportInput input)
{

    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

GetImportInput.cs

```
public string Name {get; set;}
```

---

Postman details:

```
ContentType = application/json

Body = {
            "name" : "Rabbit"
       }
```

[image: c#]

When I put a breakpoint inside my Import method, the breakpoint hits, but the parameter input does not have the value `Rabbit`. May I ask how do I properly get my postman to send the body so my controller method will pick it up.

Header Tab

[image]

Comment: Try `Name` instead of `name` in the JSON.

Comment: @ADyson name is still null, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. as well as that please also try `public async Task<IActionResult> Import([FromBody] GetImportInput input)` (see https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086673/5947043 and others)

Comment: Can you show the headers tab?

Comment: @NoahStahl posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing [FromBody] in your controller method, casing is not an issue here. Remember to use header Content-Type: application/json when testing this with Postman.

```
public class ListingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Import([FromBody]GetImportInput input)
    {
        return StatusCode(200);
    }
}
```