# How to add params in stored procedure in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddReserv
    @Place int,
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].Reserv(UserId, Place,  StartDate, EndDate)
    VALUES (1, @Place, @StartDate, @EndDate)
END
```

From the controller in the post method, I want to add a new record to the table. I can't figure out how to pass parameters to the stored procedure.

My code in the controller:

```
// POST: api/CreateReserv
[HttpPost]
public void Post(string value)
{
    using (var connection = _db.Database.GetDbConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "AddReserv";

            //How to add params?
            /*
                    @Place int
                    @StartDate datetime
                    @EndDate datetime
            */

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated my answer with some of @Karan's code (which should be the correct answer)

```
....

  using var connection = _db.Database.GetDbConnection();
  connection.Open();

  using var command = new SqlCommand("AddReserv", connection)
  {
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  };

  command.Parameters.Add("@Place", SqlDbType.Int).Value = place;
  command.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
  command.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;
  
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Further improvement will be to use an async version of the code. Note: When your code is more finished, don't forget [FromBody] if posting JSON (more info about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63349923/14072498).

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string value)
{
  await using var connection = _db.Database.GetDbConnection();
  await connection.OpenAsync();

  await using var command = new SqlCommand("AddReserv", connection)
  {
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  };

  command.Parameters.Add("@Place", SqlDbType.Int).Value = place;
  command.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
  command.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;

  await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

  ....
}
```

Not sure what type _db is, if

```
_db.Database.GetDbConnection()
```

has an async version, use that as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can add parameter using `command.Parameters.Add` like below.

Please make sure you have installed `NuGet` package [`System.Data.SqlClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/).

```
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "AddReserv";
    
    command.Parameters.Add("@Place", SqlDbType.Int).Value = place;
    command.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
    command.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;
    
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();     
}
```

Comment: I see what function `Parameters.Add` takes only one parameter and does not compile

Comment: As per document it should work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: @Karan: Small typo, SqlDbType.int -> SqlDbType.Int

Comment: `Parameters.Add takes only one parameter` - I guess you might not have installed `NuGet` [`https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/).

Comment: Things seems to work with code from @Karan. Can you please select his answer as the one?